# Is it possible to handle apple push notifications received in background?

Tags: iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Is possible to distinguish when user manually resume application or accept push notification?

I also want to handle push notification params.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `didReceiveRemoteNotification`, which is the the method that gets called when a push  notification arrives.

You need to look at the [UIApplication Delegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)! There are a couple of other methods too for remote notifications.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
if ( application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive )
    // app was already in the foreground
else
    // app was just brought from background to foreground
...
}
```

Comment: Also look at http://www.iphonedeveloperdiary.com/2010/06/receiving-apple-push-notifications-when-app-is-running/

Comment: This notification iPhone will recieve only if app in Foreground mode. If application in Background mode it will show only alert with message, but this callback is not raised.